# Flutter: Local Notifications changing name of the app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, localnotification

I have the flutter local notifications package installed and everything works just fine except for one thing:
When the screen is locked and a local notification appears, on iOS it doesn't show the real name of the App but only the name of the flutter project. And if I unlock the screen, the real name of the App appears.

I already changed the App name like you normally would do it, so going to the **android folder/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml** and also on **iOS Runner/Info.plist** and change the name.

I also changed the title inside the NotificationController, but this only effects the name of the local notification when the screen is unlocked.

How can I change it so that not depending on wether the screen is locked or unlocked, only the real App name is shown?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I guess I know whats going on. Somehow in debug mode sometimes the "real" name of the app doesn't show up but the project name. When releasing the app, this issue disappears.
So if anyone else has this problem, don't worry about it, just release the App, it will function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well when I was facing the same problem I just `searched` that name in the `Project level search` using **Ctrl+Shift+f**. After searching it will show you all the places where the old name of your application still exist then you can change them one by one.

In my case I have found app name about `15-16` places some of them I have changed already and then changed the rest.

I hope this will work for you too.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this solution didn't really worked for me..